# How to solve this error TypeError: write_points() missing 1 required positional argument: 'measurement'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, influxdb-python

I am trying to add csv data in influxdb but this code is giving error, I am not sure what this error means

```
client= DataFrameClient(host='localhost',port=)
client.write_points(json_body)


TypeError: write_points() missing 1 required positional argument: 'measurement'
```

Comment: The only code line related to your question is the last one (`client.write_points(json_body)`). Please remove everything else. However, we need to know what `client` is. Add its definition.

Comment: @DYZ  Please check now